# OWASP TOP10 - #10 Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards

Tags: security, redirect, hyperlink, forwarding, owasp

I read many of the articles to this topic, including the [OWASP PAGE](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A10) and the [Google blog article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being.html) about open redirects...
I also found this question on [open redirects here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445420/why-open-redirect-urls) but it's a different one

I know why i should not redirect ... this makes totaly sense to me.

But what I really don't understand: Where is exactly the difference between redirecting and putting this in a normal `<a href` link?
Maybe some of the users are looking in the status bar but i think most of them are not really looking to the status bar, when they klick a link.
Is this really the only reason?
like on this [article](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html) they wrote:

```
<a href="http://bank.example.com/redirect?url=http://attacker.example.net">Click here to log in</a>
```

> The user may assume that the link is safe since the URL starts with their trusted bank, bank.example.com. However, the user will then be redirected to the attacker's web site (attacker.example.net) which the attacker may have made to appear very similar to bank.example.com. The user may then unwittingly enter credentials into the attacker's web page and compromise their bank account. A Java servlet should never redirect a user to a URL without verifying that the redirect address is a trusted site.

So, if you have something like a guestbook, where the user can put the link to their homepage, then the only difference is that the link is not redirected, but it still goes to the evil webpage.

Am I seeing this problem right?

Comment: If there's a link, the user has the chance to check link target before clicking it. Also, unless you have some kind of HTML injection / XSS vulnerability on your website, *you control all your link targets*. User-provided links (as in guestbooks, etc.) should be clearly recognizable as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, it is not that the redirect is the problem.  The main problem here is allowing a redirect (where the target is potentially controllable by the user) that contains an absolute url.

The fact that the url is absolute (meaning it begins `http://host/etc`), means that you are un-intentionally allowing cross-domain redirects.  This is very similar to classic XSS vulnerabilities whereby javascript can be reflected to make cross-domain calls (and leak your domain's information).

So, as I understand, the way to fix most of these sorts of problems is to make sure that any redirect (on the server) is done relative to the root.  Then there is no way for the user-controlled query string value go somewhere else.

Does that answer your question or just create more?

Comment: I'd rather say that the problem is that there is a redirect with a user-controllable target at all. I don't see any reason why it would be sensible to allow a user-controlled redirect, even if it's relative to the domain.

Comment: @NiklasB. True, however what I meant was that the server-side redirector mustn't redirect outside the domain.  If the redirector won't go outside that massively reduces the risk (assuming that the domain has proper authorisation rules in place)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that its possible for an attacker to make the URL appear to be trustworthy as it’s actually a URL to web site the victim trusts, i. e. *bank.example.com*.

The redirect target does not need to be that obvious as in the example. Actually, the attacker will probably use further techniques to trick both the user and possibly even the web application if necessary with special encodings, [parameter pollutioning](https://www.owasp.org/images/b/ba/AppsecEU09_CarettoniDiPaola_v0.8.pdf), and other techniques to spoof a legitimate URL.

So even if a victim is so security-conscious to check a URL before clicking a link or requesting its resource otherwise, all they can verify is that the URL points to the trustworthy web site *bank.example.com*. And that alone suffices too often.

Comment: thanks, never heard of the parameter pollution before, I will read the article!